# How can I get a value from a form in another file?

Tags: php

I'm working with two files, signup.php and signup.inc.php, in order to build a signup form. However, inside the signup.inc.php file, all of the error handling is done. One of the main things that I want to check is that the password that the user typed, is the same as the one he typed in the previous box.

This would be the code extracted from signup.php:

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
<input type="password" name="secondpassword" placeholder="Retype your password">
```

And this is the way that I'm trying to retrieve the values from this file, in order to carry on the error handling; all of this is done in signup.inc.php:

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$secondpassword = $_POST['secondpassword']);
```

This would be the form markup:

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';
?>
    <section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <h2>Sign-up</h2>
      <form class="signup-form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
        <?php
          if (isset($_GET['first'])) {
            $first = $_GET['first'];
            echo '<input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name" value="'.$first.'" required>';
          } else {
            echo '<input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name" required>';
          }
          if (isset($_GET['last'])) {
            $last = $_GET['last'];
            echo '<input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last Name" value="'.$last.'" required>';
          } else {
            echo '<input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last Name" required>';
          }
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="e-mail" required>
        <input type="text" name="secondemail" placeholder="Repeat e-mail" required>
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
          $id = $_GET['id'];
          echo '<input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Username" value="'.$id.'" required>';
        } else {
          echo '<input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Username" required>';
        }
        ?>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="password" name="secondpassword" placeholder="Repeat the password" required>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign-up</button>
      </form>
```

Just in case, `$conn = msqli_connect($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName)`

That is the connection to the database.

What I'm getting is that the variable $secondpassword is actually empty, so I'm not being able to retrieve the information from the form in signup.php. Is there any way to fix this? I'm not having any trouble while using just the $password variable, but $secondpassword is causing a lot of issues.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Make both form fields `required`

Comment: Escaping one and not escaping the other could cause problems. You should never use `mysqli_escape_real_string()` on passwords.

Comment: The code you have *works* for me when the form fields are required. Both appear in the `$_POST` array. Is it possible you have other code affecting this?

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine, if you want to make sure they are both filled, you can add the `required` attribute as @JayBlanchard mentioned, and then at your `PHP` compare the values, `if ($password === $secondpassword ) { /* passwords match */ }`, and I'll suggest do that in client-side too with `JavaScript` for user convenience.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it is possible that something else is affecting the code, the code is longer and I can't identify what the problems are. Would you mind checking it if I upload both of the files to github?

Comment: have you validated your `password` inputs?

Comment: Just post the rest of the form markup in your question first, then we'll go from there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard There, I edited the question

Comment: @dean Yes, but that's not the problem, I'm having trouble with the passing of information from one file to another

Comment: `if( trim($_POST['password']) == trim($_POST['secondpassword']) ) {//proceed }else{ //pass dont match}`

Comment: @dean when I can, I'll try that and let you know!